# How to "cancel run" for all scheduled github actions at once?

Tags: github, github-actions

Is there an option to cancel runs for all scheduled github actions in one repository at once. To always go here and cancel runs is a lot of clicking.
[image]

Comment: Oct. 2021: [`gh run cancel`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69718191/6309)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [Github Actions API](https://developer.github.com/v3/actions/workflow_runs/#cancel-a-workflow-run) to list workflow runs and cancel workflows runs.

The following script use [curl](/questions/tagged/curl) [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) and [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) to :

- get ids of workflow runs with status `queued` or `in_progress`
- cancel these workflows runs

To run the script below you will need a [personnal access token](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line#creating-a-token) with repo `scope` :

```bash
token=YOUR_TOKEN
repo=your_user/your_repo

ids=$(curl -s -H "Authorization: token $token" \
     https://api.github.com/repos/$repo/actions/runs | \
     jq '.workflow_runs[] | select([.status] | inside(["in_progress", "queued"])) | .id')
set -- $ids
for i; do curl \
     -H "Authorization: token $token" \
     -X POST "https://api.github.com/repos/$repo/actions/runs/$i/cancel"; done
```

Comment: Getting this error `curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL`

Answer (score 7):

gh run list + powershell:

```
gh run list --limit 5000 --json status,databaseId -q ".[] | select (.status == \`"queued\`" ) | .databaseId" | ForEach-Object -Process { gh run cancel $_ }
```

Gets first 5000 workflows, filters it by "status" == "queued" and passes it to "gh run cancel"

Comment: Great solution! Note to users: run this in your local repo directory.

Answer (score 6):

macOS oneliner (inspired by other answers):

```
for id in $(gh run list --limit 5000 --jq ".[] | select (.status == \"queued\" ) | .databaseId" --json databaseId,status); do gh run cancel $id; done

# List 5000 runs, filters them by "status == queued", and passes them to "gh run cancel"
```

Notes:

1. Install gh cli first by `brew install gh` and `gh auth login`
2. You need to run this in your local repository.

Comment: There's something wrong here. The `--json databaseId,status` is displaced.

Answer (score 4):

Here is my GNU one-liner for cancelling all current runs:

```
$ gh run list --json databaseId -q '.[].databaseId' \
| xargs -d '\n' -n1 gh run cancel
```

Answer (score 2):

I created this [small script](https://gist.github.com/ktmud/a0a9673254524d01189a8a7000829357) to manually cancel all unfinished jobs for a given branch or pull request:

```
Example:

  # Set up
  export GITHUB_TOKEN=394ba3b48494ab8f930fbc93
  export GITHUB_REPOSITORY=apache/incubator-superset

  # Cancel previous jobs for a PR
  ./cancel_github_workflows.py 1042

  # Cancel previous jobs for a branch
  ./cancel_github_workflows.py my-branch

  # Cancel all jobs including the last ones, this is useful
  # when you have closed a PR or deleted a branch and want
  # to cancel all its jobs.
  ./cancel_github_workflows.py 1024 --include-last
```

Answer (score 2):

You also have, in Oct. 2021, [`gh run cancel`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_run_cancel)

This comes from the [GitHub CLI gh 2.2.0](https://github.com/cli/cli/releases/tag/v2.2.0) and [feature request 3775](https://github.com/cli/cli/issues/3775) (Support canceling workflow runs), implemented in [PR 3833](https://github.com/cli/cli/pull/3833) and [commit 06c06c8](https://github.com/cli/cli/commit/06c06c87dc02e5a7b50d9771ae4178bd10317e8d)

```
gh run cancel [<run-id>] [flags]
```

[`gh run list`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_run_list) can list your workflow runs ID first.